# Flutter Textfield Cursor Chipping Issue

Tags: flutter

Framework: Flutter
Language: Dart
Everywhere in the app for all the text-fields the cursor is vertically chipped.
Seemingly, I cannot find any setting which is causing this.

How can I make it full length?

[image]

I am on the latest stable flutter release: v1.9.1+hotfix.6

TextField implementation:

```
  TextEditingController phoneNumber = TextEditingController();

TextField(
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
              controller: phoneNumber,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              enabled: true,
              maxLength: 10,
              maxLengthEnforced: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(

                prefixText: '+91-',
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: This behaviour is consistent with the emulator as well as the device. On release build as well.

Comment: Could you paste how you implemented TextField

Comment: @Nuts - Added the TextField implementation.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that

Comment: @pr0gramist - well, thanks for trying. I will keep screwing my time over this I guess.